# Why is HTMLElement prototype sharing properties with all instances instead of creating copies for each element?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working with HTMLElement.prototype, because I want to add custom properties to my elements to work with. For example, I'm setting up a storage that would save properties:value keys related to THIS element.

The problem is that setting properties up on HTMLElement.prototype is sharing these properties with ALL the instances, and it's very wrong.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.storage = {};
HTMLElement.prototype.store = function(prop, val) {
  this.storage[prop] = val;
}
HTMLElement.prototype.retrieve = function(prop) {
  return this.storage[prop];
}

window.onload = function() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");

  box.store("a", "a value");
  console.log(
    box2.retrieve("a")
  );
}
```

I expect the box2 element does not possess an "a" property in his storage, because I didn't set it for THIS element. I set it for the box element instead.

Comment: You explicitly put the `storage` property on the prototype. If you want it on each element, you have to initialize it in `.store()` the first time it's called.

Comment: prototype is used mostly  for defining methods so that all the instances shares them instead of having the same copy of a method on each instance which is wasteful

Comment: So every property set directly on HTMLElement is shared among all the instances?
And the only method to change this is define property inside methods, like this:

`
HTMLElement.prototype.store = function(prop, val) {
          if(!this.storage) this.storage = {};
          this.storage[prop] = val;
        }
        HTMLElement.prototype.retrieve = function(prop) {
          return (this.storage && this.storage != undefined) ? this.storage[prop] : undefined;
        }
`

Comment: Yes that way you can Access the current instance and append/change it how you like.

Comment: weird that you are basically recreating data attributes.

Comment: @epascarello: data attributes?

Comment: : so why this is working:
[code]
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
          this.firstName = first;
          this.lastName = last;
          this.age = age;
          this.eyeColor = eye;
        }

        Person.prototype.nationality = "English";

        var f = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
        f.nationality = 'it';
        console.log(f.nationality);

        var c = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
        console.log(c.nationality);
[/code]

Comment: It could help to read something about IIFEs - discussed similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235273/iife-methods-leaks Your storage works as static member of you HTMLElement "class", you should make storage addressed by the element or remove the storage and set "a" as property of the element this[prop]=val, but not sure if it will not get lost.

Comment: @saga `f.nationality = 'it'` is adding a new property to the instance, that's why it's different, you can only use stuff from the prototype, if you want to edit it, you'll have to go to it `f.prototype.nationality = 'it'`

Comment: @saga as Zohir Salak said, `f.nationality = 'it'` creates a new property on the instance object. Properties defined on instances are said to _shadow_ the (shared) property named the same but defined on the prototype.
Then prototype chain lookup enters when accessing some property: the Javascript engine will first try to retrieve the object own property, but if it doesn't exist there the engine will try find that same property on the prototype, the prototype also has a prototype ... the lookup stop once there is no more prototype to look for ultimately resulting in the _undefined_ value.

Answer (score 2):

*storage* property is being defined on the HTMLElement's *prototype*, it is by definition [«seen by all objects through prototype chaining»](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

You can define a `store(prop, val): void` method on HTMLElement prototype and usually per instance properties are defined within the *constructor* function.

In this case, you are dealing with a built-in *constructor* function and therefore you cannot add properties there. One easy alternative is to define the `storage` property (if it doesn't exist yet) in the store method, the property will be added for the element on which the method *store* is being called.

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.store = function (key, val) {
 if (!this.storage) {
   this.storage = {};
 }
 this.storage[key] = val;
}

HTMLElement.prototype.getFromStore = function (key) {
 return this.storage ? this.storage[key] : undefined;
}

document.getElementById('one').store('test', 1);
document.getElementById('two').store('test', 2);

// Display stored values for each div element
document.body.innerHTML = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'), 0).map((el) => `${el.id}: ${el.getFromStore('test')}`).join(',');
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

```
HTMLElement.prototype.store = function(prop, val) {
    if (!this._storage) {
        this._storage = {};
    }
    this.storage[prop] = val;
}
```